# How to use redis to associate metadata with objects

Tags: redis

Say for example I have a news article in redis:

```
SET article:id '{ "title": "this is the title", "content": "this is the content" }'
```

Now say I would like to associate some metadata like a tag, say "politics". What would the idiomatic way to do this be?

Would it be to add a set for the tags with the set ID following a convention like `article:<id>:tags`?

```
SADD article:id:tags 'politics'
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to search articles and tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using [redis hash](https://redis.io/commands#hash) for that

```
HMSET article:id "title" "this is the title" "content" "this is the content" "tag" "politics"
```

If you want to fetch articles by tag, a reversed set might be better

```
SADD tags:politics article_id
```

Comment: Thank you. If I want to be able to retrieve an article by ID and I want to be able to retrieve all articles with a date range should I use a HMSET(hash map) for adding the article and a ZADD (sorted set, with timestamp as the weighting) to permit retrieval of the sorted range? (and then group these commands using MULTI?)